# Composition of Identical Functions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I have come across a problem which asks to find $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x))=-x$.  Nothing I can find has anything pertaining to the composition of two identical functions.  Is there a way that I can dissect this in order to help in finding a possible $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through late night serendipity and later verification, I have found that $f(x)=ix$ works for all real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some possible answers:

- Multiply by sqrt(-1).
- Rotate by 90 degrees.
- Map an even number `x` to `x+1`, and an odd number to `1-x`.

I don't think it is possible if `f` is continuous on real numbers.

Comment: I would the Fourier Transform help?  If I recall correctly (note that I am 15), the Fourier Transform is just converting a function from a time to a frequency domain.  Where would this be applicable to my situation?

Comment: You are right and I am wrong. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Another question, how would the last two be represented and/or transformed into a formula or equation?

Comment: You could represent the rotation as a matrix. The even/odd one is best left as a list of cases, I reckon.